# Change default icon for VLC media player Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, icons, snap, vlc, ownership

How to change the default orange cone icon for the VLC media player Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. terminal `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`
2. then go to /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications => right-click VLC, properties, click icon & select whatever you want.